# Execution of TestComplete automation scripts through powershell using TFS Release Management

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-2015

Unable to run TestComplete scripts through powershell script using TFS Release Management task "Powershell on Target Machines".

The task is initiated in Release management and never completes. Are there any special arguments to be passed to powershell script in order to execute the test script interactively.

Manually running the powershell script on the release agent machine executes without any issue.[image]

Comment: Can you share the logs?

Answer (score 0):

The Script argument are the arguments required by the script, if any.
-NoProfile is an argument which powershell.exe accepts, try removing that.

Comment: Tried removing -NoProfile argument, but this change does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Does your script RunTC.ps1 expect any arguments to be passed to it ?

Comment: Yes, RunTC.ps1 srcipts runs successfully without any arguments being passed to it.

Comment: I just noted that you are running the script C:\RunTC.ps1 on the application server machine. Does that machine have the script in the required path ?

Also assuming that the credentials being used to connect to the application server and running the script over WinRM are correct.

Comment: The script exists in the path mentioned, the credentials provided are also valid. One more observation i was able to note is that the TestComplete process is alive on the Release agent(Application Server), once i kill the process the powershell task completes, until then the powershell task is active and does not exit.

Comment: I would advice writing some sort of log on filesystem/ eventlog to see if the script is actually being called here and put try catch statements within the script to handle exceptions. You can enable PowerShell logging to on the application server to get more insight into this -> Read [here] (https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2016/02/greater_visibilityt.html)